# Alternative approach to non parametric method when we have small sample sizes

Tags: nonparametric, small-sample, ancova

I have one continuous dependent, one categorical independent and one continuous covariate. So my first statistical approach was `ANCOVA`, however, the sample sizes in each group are around 15. Someone suggested me using `nonparametric ANCOVA` which I am not familiar with this method. How is the accuracy of this model? Is there any alternative statistical approach?

Comment: It's sometimes said (and I've even read it in books) that you should use nonparametric methods when you have small sample sizes. I've no idea what the justification is for this. Perhaps you can ask the recommender?

Comment: @ Jeremy Miles, thanks for the comment, unfortunately, he is not available.

Comment: @Jeremy Miles, can we use regression when the sample sizes are small?

Comment: If you didn't violate any assumptions, there's no reason not to use regression. It's harder to tell that you haven't violated assumptions when the sample size is small, and you (of course) have very little power.